# The request in invalid - unrecognized type: string when applying kubectl

Tags: yaml, kubectl

I am applying a `yaml` file using `kubectl` on running pods but am getting the following error (changed some values for confidentiality reasons. What is the issue? The error is not descriptive unfortunately.

```
The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[metadata:map[annotations:map[kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"appnameweb\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"replicas\":1,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"app\":\"appnameweb\"}},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"appnameweb\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"env\":[{\"name\":\"DB_CASSANDRA_URI\",\"value\":\"3x.yy.zz.pqe\"},{\"name\":\"RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY_TEST\",\"value\":\"6something-moreJWe\"},{\"name\":\"RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY_PROD\",\"value\":\"6something_more-I\"},{\"name\":\"HOSTDOMAIN\",\"value\":\"mydomain.space\"},{\"name\":\"MOCK_EMAIL\",\"value\":false},{\"name\":\"START_MODE\",\"value\":\"prod\"},{\"name\":\"DB_CASSANDRA_PORT\",\"value\":\"9042\"},{\"name\":\"DB_PASSWORD\",\"value\":\"something-passwordy-jhidden_mhereQ\"},{\"name\":\"DB_KEYSPACE_NAME\",\"value\":\"keyspacename\"},{\"name\":\"DB_USERNAME\",\"value\":\"someuser\"},{\"name\":\"EMAIL_SERVER\",\"value\":\"email-domaint-2.domain.com\"},{\"name\":\"EMAIL_USER\",\"value\":\"ABCDEFGHT\"},{\"name\":\"EMAIL_PASSWORD\",\"value\":\"BwithPlus+pwqref\"},{\"name\":\"ALLOWED_NODES\",\"value\":\".\"},{\"name\":\"PSK\",\"value\":\"key-key\"}],\"image\":\"docker.io/imagepath:29122020\",\"name\":\"appnameweb\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":9000}],\"volumeMounts\":[{\"mountPath\":\"/deploy/appnameweb-1.0/logs/\",\"name\":\"shared-logs\"}]}],\"imagePullSecrets\":[{\"name\":\"codingjedi-docker-registry\"}],\"volumes\":[{\"emptyDir\":{},\"name\":\"shared-logs\"}]}}}}\n]] spec:map[template:map[spec:map[]]]]": unrecognized type: string
```

Comment: I had to put the value false in double quotes